# Can I install Mac OS X Lion (10.7) on my Windows XP PC?

Tags: mac, windows

I am using Windows XP, now I want to install Mac OS X Lion (10.7). My problem is I want both operating systems. Is it possible? Will it be possible to use Mac OS X Lion (10.7) and XP simultaneously?

Comment: Questions about installing Mac OS X on non-Apple hardware are off-topic for this site as per the [FAQ].

Comment: Better idea:  Buy a Mac.  Install VM s/w such as VMWare or Parallels.  Then install WinXP (or Win7) in the VM.  Then you can use them simultaneously and be legal at the same time.

Comment: Yes you certainly can do it, but in many cases, you might not want to risk the licensing issues if you don't have a legal team to know the risks of a potential violation. As long as we can keep this objective and informative, I don't see this needing to be closed. If it gets into a "how to accomplish this" we may need to edit or close this. We're happy to host a high level summary of issues, but **we are not the place to find a "how to run Lion on non-Apple hardware"**.

Answer (score 6):

Questions that detail how to actually installation of OS X on non-Apple hardware are off topic due to the **violation of the Apple EULA**, but let's see if we can have a good general discussion of the issues and assume everyone is here to learn where the virtualization issues lie.

### Using non-Apple hardware

Your only option is a **[hackint0sh](http://www.hackint0sh.org/tutorials-217/)**.

### Using a Mac computer

If you were using a Mac computer, you can use both operating systems:

- **simultaneously**:

  OS X (host), XP ([virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine))
- **dual boot** via [bootcamp](https://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/):

  OS X, XP ← this will allow XP full access to the hardware

  **Note:**

  - Bootcamp in Lion does not support Windows XP. 
    (Thanks to @DanBarrett for mentioning this)

  It [only supports](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4818#3):

  - Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium, Microsoft Windows 7 Professional, or Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate with Boot Camp 4.0. Check [this list](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1846) for information on 64-bit support.

Comment: I think it's also possible to use XP as a host via bootcamp and virtualize OSX.

Comment: He wants to install Lion, so XP in Bootcamp isn't an option since Lion Bootcamp only supports Windows 7.

Comment: @DanBarrett All right, thanks! I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: However, we can use a russian doll metaphor to boot Windows 7 in BootCamp and then virtualize an XP instance in that to avoid any Mac OS. It's a stretch if the OP would accept it, but it's certainly possible and clearly within EULA of Windows and Apple if proper licenses are used.

Answer (score 2):

There is a second way you can run on Windows hardware, although it pretty clearly seems in **violation of the Apple EULA** (at least to a non-laywer).

You can download and install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). It will emulate the Mac OS X hardware and you can [run Mac OS X on your Windows](http://lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows) (this tutorial mentions Snow Leopard, but Lion will work as well).
It isn't easy (or recommended...) but this solution is pretty close to the answer you are looking for.

**Please note, although they say you can download a copy of Snow Leopard/Lion, this is illegal. You'll have to buy a legal copy of the installation disk in order to do this legally...**

Comment: Keep in mind though that using a virtualization of OSX on a PC still is a **violation of the Apple EULA**.

Comment: Hm, I thought so... Does this make my answer unsuitable for this site? I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: As long as you yourself don't give directions on how to do this, you should be fine - I think... :)

Comment: I see :-) I'll edit my answer!

Comment: Great discussion - trying to be clear of legality and just covering the bases seems a good thing to have. I'll ping another moderator to be sure we're in the clear here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the extra pair of eyes. Please notify me if things are illegal, so I can edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can install Mac on your Windows computer using [VMWare Player](http://appletoolbox.com/2016/03/install-mac-on-windows-pc-laptop/), which is a non-commercial software. It's easy, quick, and you can get a Mac OS X running within minutes.